# Hit Number attribute equivalent in GA4 Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there an equivalent of the attribute Hit Number from UA structure into GA4 structure in Bigquery. i'm trying to identify a unique row/event but except using hash key generator.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So, in GA4 everything every hit is an event and there is no distinction between Hit types as in UA.

Say you want to know the total number of hits on a given day, e.g. October 25th this year:

```
select 
  count(distinct event_timestamp) as cnt_hits
from
  `analytics_123456789.events_*`
where
  _table_suffix = '20211025' and
  event_name = 'page_view'
```

In this case, the event `'page_view'` is triggered every time someone sees any of your web's pages.

To get a better sense, if you had an event called `'added_to_cart'`, then inputing that in the previous WHERE clause and counting the distinct event_timestamps would give you the total hits on that specific event (which would be basically triggered by a specific action, as clicking the "Add to cart" button).

Answer (score 0):

SELECT
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_pseudo_id ORDER BY user_pseudo_id,event_timestamp,event_name) AS user_event_number,
*
FROM
`Project-bq1.analytics_290070127.events_*`
WHERE
_table_suffix between '20220501' and '20220510'

you can refer 'user_event_number' for hit number after running the code